# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I need help, don't see anything suspicious :c thanks for help !

`Error Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist` occurs after the call:

```
 public function show(Request $request, User $user)
 {
        $user->load('permissions');
        dd($with);
        return UserResource::make($user);
 }
```

User Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    (...)

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///
    ///  Relationships
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Relationship to permissions
     *
     * @return RolePermissions
     */
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->role()->first()->permissions;
    }
}
```

Comment: try :
  return $this->role()->with('permissions')->get()-> first()->permissions;

Comment: Do you have a table `permissions`? Or is `permissions` just a column in `roles`?

Comment: @OMR That still won't work; you can't call `->load()` on a non-relationship, and unless Permission is a model (which I suspect it isn't), this code needs to be changed.

Comment: if you are using standard laravel user , u could simply remove your 'permissions' relation and use the ready-made one:

$permissionNames = $user->getPermissionNames(); // collection of name strings
$permissions = $user->permissions;  // get the user permissions

Comment: Thanks I resolved problem :) Thank you very much

Comment: please mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using standard laravel user ,
 you have to remove your 'permissions' relation and use the ready-made one:

```
$permissionNames = $user->getPermissionNames(); // collection of name strings 
$permissions = $user->permissions; // get the user permissions
```

if you want a user with its permissions:

```
$user->load('permissions');
```

more details in:

https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/basic-usage/